# Elastic Search Global Histogram Across Nested Data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested aggregation like below trying to get counts per week per id, and I'm trying to get the distribution (percentiles or histogram) for the results globally (ie not just histogram per week). Here is my query:

```
"aggs": {
    "by_week": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "create_time", 
        "interval": "week"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And the output is essentially something like

```
week 1
-id1: 5
-id2: 3
week2: 
-id1: 5
-id2: 4
```

Now, I would like to get a distribution of the counts, something like

```
3 -> 1
4 -> 1
5 -> 2
```

Anyone have any idea how to do something like this?